Proof for the alternative form of integration by parts
We all know the integration by parts which is $\int udv = uv-\int vdu.$ 
But today my sir gave us a new format. For example, lets consider $\int_0^x g(x)f(x) dx$ which is simplified to $[f(x)\int g(x)\ dx] - [\int [\int g(x)\ dx].f'(x) dx]]$. This method works for almost every cases. We also use ILATE condition for this method and here f(x) should be the prior one in ILATE.
I tried proving this alternative method but got no idea how to prove this. 
Please help me get to know the proof for this.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

$u=f(x)$, $v=\int g(x) dx$ and it's the same thing written in different notation.

Sorry but I can't understand completely what you are saying can you please explain more clearly with the help of notations

$(f \cdot g)' = f'g + fg'$ which is the Product rule
That gives $f'g = (f \cdot g)' - fg'$
Now integrate all 3 parts, but instead of f' use F' with $F=\int fdx$

f'g at LHS is same as the gf' in RHS. So do you mean 2f'g=(fg)'

There were a few typos which I corrected now , @RishwanthSV , you might recheck it now.

@Prem thanks for the edits now I understand the proof.
